# vserver blocks proxy in php curl code

Tags: php, curl, proxy, server

I am using curl for getting information for my website. This works well so far with the following php code:

```
$options = array(

            CURLOPT_URL             => $url, 

            CURLOPT_HTTPGET         => true,            
            CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE       => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 ,       
            CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE       => 7,               
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => "session/cookie1.txt",   
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => true, 
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",    
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,  
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,  
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,  
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,   
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,  
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false, 
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_COOKIE         => $cookiesIn,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,  

            CURLOPT_PROXY          => $proxyIP, 
            CURLOPT_PROXYPORT       => $proxyPORT, 
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => "GET", 

            CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL => false, 


            CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT       => 2 
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );


        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $rough_content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
```

It has always worked, but since I added the GET parameters in customrequest I can not get any results anymore on the server (Win2008). Running it on the server results in no error or any message. It is just being executed unlimited (one page is running since days as I was hoping to get an useful error message). When running it on my laptop there is no problem at all and all information can be retrieved.

Does anyone know which parameter causes the problem? It can't be the proxy server as it works properly on my laptop. So I guess it is a DNS issue, but I have no idea what is causing this or how I can avoid it.

Comment: The default method is GET so unless you have used another method elsewhere not shown then you do not need `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` nor the custom request??

Comment: Stating it works on your laptop does not mean it should work on your server... they could be on two totally different networks. Is the proxyserver a local server or remote?

Comment: The proxy is remote.